# No Camera Found in Scene error message, when clearly there is a camera. Why?

Tags: rendering, camera, error

[image]

Hey Fellow Blenderers!

Here's my issue.

I have a camera in my scene. The Scene is labeled "Main Scene", the camera is labeled "camera". Yet, when I go to render an image I get the error message "No camera found in scene "Main Scene" which is not true. Can anyone tell me what's going on? The Image I've attached clearly shows the camera fully active and in the correct scene. I haven't been able to find anyone else with this particular issue.

Also, I'm using 2.8 RC2.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other errors preceding this one printed on the console? Can't see anything wrong either.

Comment: There wasn't I only solved the issue by guessing and placing a camera in the separate Scene I had created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. I had created a second scene where I added a separate HDRI to use in the compositor for some fun effects. Apparently all your scenes require a camera no matter which scene you wish to render.

So once I added a camera to the second scene, the camera in Main Scene finally worked.